# how to change scales title position in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

can we change title position ( month and number ) to end of x and y scales (like expected picture) in chart.js 3.5

expected : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlr6R.png

actual : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcD7c.png

here is options setting :

```
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: 0,
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          align: "center",
          text: "number",
          color: "#242424",
        },
      },
      x: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          align: "center",
          text: "month",
          color: "#242424",
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "bottom",
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: here is code : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/scale-options/titles.html

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

You cant achieve this by default, you will need to use a custom plugin for this:

```js
const customTitle = {
  id: 'customTitle',
  beforeLayout: (chart, args, opts) => {
    if (!opts.x.display) {
      return;
    }

    const {
      ctx
    } = chart;
    ctx.font = opts.x.font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'

    const {
      width
    } = ctx.measureText(opts.x.text);
    chart.options.layout.padding.right = width * 1.3;
  },
  afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      ctx,
      scales: {
        x,
        y
      },
      chartArea: {
        top,
        bottom,
        left,
        right
      }
    } = chart;

    if (opts.x.display) {
      ctx.fillStyle = opts.x.color || Chart.defaults.color
      ctx.font = opts.x.font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
      ctx.fillText(opts.x.text, (right + (opts.x.offsetX || 0)), (bottom + ((opts.x.offsetY * -1) || 0)))
    }

    if (opts.y.display) {
      ctx.fillStyle = opts.y.color || Chart.defaults.color
      ctx.font = opts.y.font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
      ctx.fillText(opts.y.text, opts.y.offsetX || 3, (top + ((opts.y.offsetY * -1) || -15)))
    }
  }
}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 0 // Seems neccesarry to put to 0, otherwise seems to not update padding
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      customTitle: {
        y: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Numbers'
        },
        x: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Month',
          offsetX: 5,
          offsetY: 5,
          font: '12px Comic Sans MS'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [customTitle]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```